# How to make sure the users see the new logo?

Tags: css, background-image, page-refresh

We redid the logo for our website, and I want to ensure that users see the new image when they come to our page. The logo is a background-image for a div. How do I ensure that the css is refreshed when the users come to the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the URL of the CSS to i.e. `style.css?newVersion=1`.

Comment: I remember doing it once and it didn't work, I still needed to refresh with F5 to see changes... Are you sure it works on all browsers?

Comment: If your HTML document is cached too, then the new link to the CSS will not be loaded, because it's never seen by the browser.

Answer (score 3):

Add an unused querystring parameter (eg, `?version=2011-06-01`) to create a new, uncached URL.

Answer (score 1):

One sure (ime) way is to embed the logo background image right in the css:

```
.div-with-logo-image-inside {
  background-image:url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhhwASAPcAAAAAABD ... ");
}
```